# "Unable to find an entry point named [function] in dll" (c++ to c# type conversion)

Tags: c#, c++, dll, dllimport, extern

I have a dll which comes from a third party, which was written in C++.
Here is some information that comes from the dll documentation:

```
//start documentation

RECO_DATA{
wchar_t Surname[200];
wchar_t Firstname[200];
}
```

Description:
Data structure for receiving the function result. All function result will be
stored as Unicode (UTF-8).

Method:

```
bool recoCHN_P_Name(char *imgPath,RECO_DATA *o_data);
```

Input:

```
char * imgPath
```

the full path of the image location for this
            function to recognize

```
RECO_DATA * o_data
```

data object for receiving the function
            result.
    Function return:
        True if Success, otherwise false will return.

```
//end documentation
```

I am trying to call the recoCHN_P_Name from my C# application. To this end, I came up with this code:

The code to import the dll:

```
    public class cnOCRsdk
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct RECO_DATA{
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=200)]
        public string FirstName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 200)]
        public string Surname;
        }

    [DllImport(@"cnOCRsdk.dll", EntryPoint="recoCHN_P_Name")]
    public static extern bool recoCHN_P_Name(byte[] imgPath, RECO_DATA o_data);
}
```

The code to call the function:

```
            cnOCRsdk.RECO_DATA recoData = new cnOCRsdk.RECO_DATA();

        string path = @"C:\WINDOWS\twain_32\twainrgb.bmp";

        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(path);

        bool res = cnOCRsdk.recoCHN_P_Name(bytes, recoData);
```

And the error I'm getting is
""Unable to find an entry point named 'recoCHN_P_Name' in DLL 'cnOCRsdk.dll'."
I'm suspecting that I'm having an error in converting a type from C++ to C#. But where exactly ... ?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

First make sure the function is actually exported:

In the Visual Studio Command Prompt, use `dumpbin /exports whatever.dll`

Comment: I have a line in the output which says

"14 D 00007B40 ?recoCHN_P_Name@CcnOCRsdk@@QAE_NPADPAURECO_DATA@@@Z"

what does that tell me?

Comment: See http://www.kegel.com/mangle.html for a detailed explanation of how to decrypt it.  Make sure you've got the datatypes correct.

Answer (score 32):

C# doesn't support C++ name mangling and you either need to declare the C++ functions with

```
extern "C" {...}
```

(may not an option if they're from a third party), or call the mangled name directly if you can get it to work. It may be easier to get the third party to provide a non-mangled interface to the functionality.

Comment: That was it in my case, thanks!

Answer (score 19):

Solved - at least to the point where the program does not break and actually returns me a bool value.

The key, I guess, was to specify the entry point as the 'mangled' name

```
    [DllImport(@"cnOCRsdk.dll", EntryPoint="?recoCHN_P_Name@CcnOCRsdk@@QAE_NPADPAURECO_DATA@@@Z")]
    public static extern bool recoCHN_P_Name(ref string imgPath, ref RECO_DATA o_data);
```

After that I got some other errors but the 'unable to find entry point' went away.

Comment: This will work but you'll have to change the mangled name if anything about the function (signature) changes. It's recommended to define them in the DLL with `extern "C"` as mentioned above.

Comment: @Goku, you can find it with a program called PE Explorer (http://www.heaventools.com/overview.htm) or the program called `dumpbin.exe` which comes with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 7):

I solved the same problem in these steps:
**step 1)** If you program your custom DLL in C++ using Visual studio,then at the property page of your project set the `Common Language Runtime Support (/clr)`parameter to `Common Language Runtime Support (/clr)`. 
**step 2)** To function deceleration in `.h` file use `__declspec(dllexport)` keyword like below:

```
__declspec(dllexport) double Sum(int a,int b);
```

**step 3)** Build and export DLL file, then use the **Dependency Walker** software to get your function **EntryPoint**.

**step4)** Import DLL file In the C# project and set **EntryPoint** and **CallingConvention** variable like below:

```
[DllImport("custom.dll", EntryPoint = "?Sum@@YAXHHHHHHNNN@Z", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]

    public static extern double Sum(int a,int b);
```

Comment: `__declspec(dllexport)` was key for me, [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/315064/6620171) has people marking them with `extern "C"`instead, and nothing was being exported, THANKS!

Comment: Thanks! I've seen about 10 solutions that recommend using "extern C" as well as  "__declspec(dllexport)". The C++ compiler wouldn't work with extern but I was unable to work out why. This worked first time for me.

Answer (score 4):

I'd write a wrapper using C++/CLI. This wrapper will be able to include the .h files and link to the .lib files you got from the third party vendor. Then it is both easy and safe to write a managed interface for your C# program.

Answer (score 2):

Correct **EntryPoint** string could be found in ".lib" file that comes along with main unmanaged dll.

Answer (score 1):

We had this problem when we want to access to DB and solved it by changing EF core to EF 6.4.4
It may be you have a problem like this and need to change or downgrade your version of EF (If you used EF)

Answer (score 1):

you may get this error due to string marshalling mismatch between DLL and your application . for example, one is using ANSI and the other is unicode.

you can try something like this:

```
 [DllImport("yourDLL.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode )]
 public static extern String YourFunction(String name);
```

checkout [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.entrypointnotfoundexception?view=net-6.0) for a list of other possible reasons.

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem .we change EntityFramework.core to EntityFrameWork 6.4.4 and after that the program worked fine. you most change you're Framework Version.

Answer (score -1):

You could try using the unmangled name while specifying a CallingConvention in the DllImport