# "Unable to find an entry point named" in c# using a C dll

Tags: c#

I am trying a simple program to access a C function through a dll into a C# program,

```
class DllImportTest
{
    [DllImport("TestApp.dll", EntryPoint = "main1")]
    public static extern void main1();
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DllImportTest.main1() ;
    }
```

I have seen through the code and the name of the function is the exactly right. I have also tried using Extern "C" but, it throws me an error as its .C file. 
I have placed the .Dll in the C# executable folder.
Is there something that I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653178/unable-to-find-an-entry-point-named-function-in-dll-c-to-c-sharp-type-con

Comment: How about calling the same method from a native C client to test whether it is a C#/.NET issue or the library is just not valid.

Comment: I was able to create a .lib for the same and run it through a C console app, and this worked file.

Comment: Make sure that the library contains this function: `dumpbin.exe /exports TestApp.dll`. You will see a list of exported functions. If you don't see `main1` in this list then there's a problem with your library.

Comment: Check out following two links, http://www.nag.co.uk/IndustryArticles/Calling_C_Library_DLLs_from_C_sharp.pdf http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6912/Calling-methods-from-Dll-compiled-in-C-from-C

Comment: @Darin 

File Type: DLL

  Summary

        1000 .data
        1000 .idata
        2000 .rdata
        1000 .reloc
        1000 .rsrc
        4000 .text
       10000 .textbss

this is what I got from the dumpbin.exe

Comment: So no `main1`? It seems your library doesn't contain such exported function. That's not surprising because that's the error you get when you try to invoke it.

Comment: the following is what I used to create the Library in visual studio 2010 : File -> New Project -> create source file -> write code -> solution properties -> config properties-> configuration type = dynamic library -> build the code and copy the .dll , Have I done something wrong??? or have I missed out anything??

Comment: File Type: LIBRARY

  Summary

         8A4 .debug$S
          64 .debug$T
          41 .drectve
           E .rdata
           4 .rtc$IMZ
           4 .rtc$TMZ
          49 .text 

This is the .lib dump that was generated, although it doesn't have main1(), it executes perfectly with a C console app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it! 
 I had to use Extern "C" coupled with __declspec(dllexport) . I had never used both together, Thanks guys