# How to add a C++ DLL in Windows Phone 8 (C#) Framework

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2012, dllimport, windows-phone-8

I am trying to add a C++ DLL to `Windows Phone 8` framework in Visual Studio Express 2012.

I have tried following ways

1. Import and invoke through PInvoke

   > [DllImport("WP8DLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
   >
   > public static extern int functionReturningInteger();

   **Result:** This way though there were no compile errors, but when I try to access the method of the DLL it throws `System.NotSupportedException`.
2. Adding reference in the project properties

   **Result:** I get the message "*A reference to a higher version or incompatible assembly cannot be added to the project*"

Comment: I'm sure this question has been asked a whole bunch of times so it may be closed as a duplicate; however I did a quick google search and yielded http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9826/How-to-create-a-DLL-library-in-C-and-then-use-it-w

Comment: "When I try to access the method of a dll it shows an exception" It's no fun for us that we have to try and guess what the exception is. You can see it we can't. Don't conceal the information from us.

Comment: The exception that I get is "System.NotSupportedException"

Comment: possible duplicate of [using a class defined in a c++ dll in c# code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315051/using-a-class-defined-in-a-c-dll-in-c-sharp-code)

Comment: How was the DLL built? Was it built for the correct CPU architecture for what you're trying to run (ARM for device, X86 for emulator)? Is it built against Windows Phone 8 headers and libraries or against full Windows?

Comment: Not all windows dll's will work on mobile devices.
They can depend on different hardware.
Your error is quite clear about that..

Comment: Not done much with Windows 8 yet, however @Iris-Classon had a post a while back about using SQLite on Windows 8, which is C++ based. May be of use: http://www.irisclasson.com/2012/10/02/winrt-app-guide-step-10-adding-a-lightweight-database-sqlite-and-crud-support-two-way-element-binding/

Answer (score 5):

You cannot add a reference from a Managed Windows Phone 8 Project directly to a native static or native dynamic library. You will need to create a Windows Phone Runtime Component. Those can be referenced by you UI project and also it can reference C++ projects, etc.

See for example [this link](http://www.jarredcapellman.com/2012/11/03/how-to-get-c-winrt-in-a-windows-phone-8-application/) for more information.