# cannot add C++/CLI dll to windows phone

Tags: dll, import, windows-phone-8, c++-cli, transplant

I have a C++/CLI project which produce a DLL.
C# project can successfully call this DLL.

**Then I want to call this DLL in my windows phone project.**

So I changed the C++/CLI project's "Property Page->general->Platform Toolset" to Windows Phone 8.0(v110). Then I changed its "Property Page->Platform" to Active(ARM).

after some bugs fixed, I try to reference new DLL in my windows phone project, only to receive   this Error : "A reference to a higher version or incompatible assembly cannot be added to the project".

YOU CAN HEAR MY HEART BREAKS!!!

What I should do now?
What kind of DLL can a windows phone project reference??
Or another way to import this project to windows phone project ???
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have that work, you need to create a Windows Phone Runtime project that your main WP8 project can reference. In it, you can reference your c++/CLI dll and then create whatever wrapper/interface methods you need to do work on it. [This previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474189/how-to-add-a-c-dll-in-windows-phone-8-c-framework) explains that process, along with a link to a sort-of tutorial on it.

Comment: Could not add a reference to file . because it is neither a .NET assembly nor a registered ActiveX control...

Comment: Is that when adding the Win RT reference to the main project, or when adding the c++ reference to the Win RT project?