# Windows Phone 8 app: using Platform Invoke

Tags: windows-phone-8, dllimport

I'm trying to use Platform Invoke functionality in Windows Phone 8 application and getting NotSupportedException. 
I'm doing something like this:

```
  [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("PhoneDLL1.dll")]
  public static extern void CallMeInC(int num);
```

....

```
  CallMeInC(100);
```

Am I doing something wrong or this functionality is not supported for Windows Phone 8 apps ?
Thanks,
Rafi

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a C++ DLL in Windows Phone 8 (C#) Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474189/how-to-add-a-c-dll-in-windows-phone-8-c-framework)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, DllImport is not supported in Windows Phone. Currenty, the only workaround is to write a native component that mimics the behavior of DllImport and then referene that component from your managed code project.

more info here: [Forum thread on MSDN](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/777333/add-dllimport-support-for-net-in-windows-phone-8)
and here: [Blog post on how to combine native code and managed code in Windows Phone](http://www.jarredcapellman.com/2012/11/03/how-to-get-c-winrt-in-a-windows-phone-8-application/)