# Why when I try to create dll in C++ project I'm having a problem in the main?

Tags: c++, dll

I'm trying to create a dll from a C++ project

I followed this link:

[using a class defined in a c++ dll in c# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315051/using-a-class-defined-in-a-c-dll-in-c-sharp-code)

And I encountered a problem:

```
DLL entry point "int __cdecl main (int, wchar_t * * const)" (? Main @@ $$ HYAHHQAPA_W @ Z) cannot be managed; compile to native
```

I changed the `int main` to:

`int _tmain (int argc, _TCHAR * argv [])`

But I ran into a problem:

```
unresolved external symbol _main
```

Comment: There's no `main` in a dynamic library.

Comment: A DLL should not have a `main` function. It should have a [`DLLMain`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dllmain) function.

Comment: If I download the main I get an unresolved external symbol _main error

Comment: Are you using .net / CLR with your dll? Or is this going to be used on standard `c++`?

Comment: ***If I download the main I get an unresolved external symbol _main error*** I would guess you selected the wrong project type for a native c++ dll.

Comment: I changed properties instead of .exe to dll

Comment: You probably want to go through this tutorial: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=vs-2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=vs-2019)

Comment: First of all the message "cannot be managed" indicates that you're building a managed project (C++/CLI). Secondly, if the project requires a `main` function then you're building an application and not a DLL.

Comment: I have an existing project and I can't build another one

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio then your solution can contain many projects. The source files could be shared between projects (although it's better to put common code into their own DLL projects and then reuse the DLL's instead).