# Import C++ DLL Pointers-to-functions to C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, dllimport

I am working on import C++ DLL Pointers-to-functions to C#.

My Code C++:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) deviceImport
{
public:
    deviceImport();
    virtual ~deviceImport();
    int __stdcall init(char* deviceName); 
    int __stdcall close();
    int __stdcall getDLLVersion(char* value); 

private:
    int handle;
    HINSTANCE hDLLDevice;
    bool __stdcall getProcAddresses( HINSTANCE *p_hLibrary, const char* p_dllName, int p_count, ... ); 
    int (__stdcall *Device_setPassword)(const char* value);
    int (__stdcall *Device_getDLLVersion)(int p_handle, char* value); 

};
```

My code C#:

```
[DllImport(dllLocation, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int init([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string device);

//How to Import Device_setPassword and Device_getDLLVersion functions???
```

I can import init function but can you help me to import Device_setPassword and Device_getDLLVersion functions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using a class defined in a c++ dll in c# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315051/using-a-class-defined-in-a-c-dll-in-c-sharp-code)

Comment: @Blu3Souls I have tried to marshall C++ as in the link. But I do not know how to call and parse `int (__stdcall *Device_setPassword)(const char* value);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my question. It might help others. Solution:

```
[DllImport(dllLocation, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern int Device_setPassword(string password);

[DllImport(dllLocation, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern int Device_getDLLVersion(int handle, out string value);
```