# Does C# remove my (unmanaged) pointer or do I need to do it manually?

Tags: c#, dll, garbage-collection

Preamble: I mostly know C++ but don't know much about C# and garbage collection.
I am attempting to make a C++ class, export it to a dll, and then use it in a C# form.
Using JaredPar's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315051/using-a-class-defined-in-a-c-dll-in-c-sharp-code) as a template.

I imported my constructor and destructor

```
[DllImport("CppDll.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr seqGen_Create();

[DllImport("CppDll.dll")]
public static extern void seqGen_Delete(IntPtr seqPtr);
```

and create an instance with

```
IntPtr seqPtr = seqGen_Create();
```

Now my C++ memory leak senses are tingling, since I created an object but don't call

```
seqGen_Delete(IntPtr seqPtr)
```

Does C# do this for me, even in a dll object, or do I need to do it manually?

If manual, is there a function that is called when the form closes? Seems like the logical place to put it.

Edit: Etienne answered the question - no, C# doesn't do this for me. Through more searching I found there isn't a function defined anywhere that runs when the form closes, but you can create a function and tie it to the FormClosed event. That is where I will call seqGen_Delete().

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then add your code to the question itself, not on an external site.

Comment: The garbage collector only handles _managed_ memory. This is _unmanaged_ memory, so you'll have to do it yourself. But even then, the .NET runtime has absolutely no idea what you're doing in your C++ code. It's not magic. Your code, as written, leaks. You will have to call `seqGen_Delete` eventually (or, better yet, wrap the whole thing in a safe handle).

Answer (score 0):

What's the point of doing this in `c#` when you have `DLLMain`?
I would recommend unloading the `dll` after the completion of the process and the `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` event.

It's not entirely clear what you want to do.
Directly delete an object?

**C++:**

```
void * __stdcall CreateCppDll() {
    return new CppDll;
}

void __stdcall DestroyCppDll(void * objptr) {
    CppDll *cppDll= (CppDll *) objptr;
    if (cppDll) {
        delete cppDll;
    }
}
```

**C#:**

```
objptr = CreateCppDll();
DestroyCppDll(objptr);
```

Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

No C# will not do this for you, you need to call `Delete` yourself. C# can only manage the "managed" references, it doesn't know anything about unmanaged pointers.

So if you were doing this all in one function, you should use a `finally`

```cs
IntPtr seqPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
try
{
    seqPtr = seqGen_Create();
    // etc
}
finally
{
    seq_Delete(seqPtr);
}
```

If you need to store this pointer in a field then the object needs to be `IDisposable` with a finalizer, and then you can put the `Delete` in the `Dispose` method.

In your case it sounds like you have a `Form`, so you need to remove `Dispose` from the Designer.cs file, and do it yourself

```cs
public override Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        components?.Dispose();
        // Dispose other managed stuff here
    }

    // Dispose of unmanaged resources here, and invoke base dispose.
    seq_Delete(seqPtr);

    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```