# P/Invoke c++ exported function from c# library char* emty in dll

Tags: c#, cmake, c++17, pinvoke

I have made a c++ console application master-project with cmake and vc++ in VS Code.

This is the CMakeLists.txt of the master-project.

```
include_directories(include)
include_directories(../sub-project/include)

set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
make_directory(${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH})

add_executable (master-project
                "source/*.cpp")
target_compile_features(master-project PUBLIC cxx_std_17)
target_link_libraries(master-project 
                      sub-project)
```

This c++ project contains a shared library sub-project as a dependency.
This is the  CMakeLists.txt of the sub-project:

```
include(GenerateExportHeader)
include_directories(include)

set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
make_directory(${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH})

add_library(sub-project SHARED "source/*.cpp" ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/sub-project_exports.h)
GENERATE_EXPORT_HEADER(sub-project
                       BASE_NAME sub-project
                       EXPORT_MACRO_NAME SUB-PROJECT_EXPORTS
                       EXPORT_FILE_NAME ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/sub-project_exports.h
                       STATIC_DEFINE SHARED_EXPORTS_BUILT_AS_STATIC)
target_include_directories(sub-project
                           PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
target_compile_features(sub-projectPUBLIC cxx_std_17)
target_link_libraries(sub-project
                      pqxx)
```

sub-project.hpp

```
#include "sub-project_exports.h"

class SUB-PROJECT_EXPORTS foo
{
public int bar(char* msg);
}
```

sub-project.cpp

```
#include "sub-project.hpp"

int foo::bar(char* msg)
{
cout<<"msg string:"<<msg<<" and msg len:"<<strlen(msg)<<endl;
return strlen(msg);
}
```

As you can notice, whole class foo is exported using cmake's 'GENERATE_EXPORT_HEADER' function.

I want to use this this exported class in sub-project.dll from a c# library project. The c# code used is:

```
[DllImport("sub-project.dll",
            EntryPoint = "foo_mangledname",
            CharSet = CharSet.Ansi,
            CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern void Foo();

[DllImport("sub-project.dll",
            EntryPoint = "bar_mangledname",
            CharSet = CharSet.Ansi,
            CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern int Bar([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string msg);
```

I used the `DUMPBIN /EXPORT` command from developer powershell of visual studio to find the mangled names of exported members.

Use of the imported functions in c#:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
string msg = "Print this message";
Console.WriteLine("Returned msg.length():" + Bar(msg))
}
```

The expected output on console is:

```
msg string:Print this message and msg len:18
Returned msg.length():18
```

But the actual output I'm getting

```
msg string: and msg len:0
Returned msg.length():0
```

I've tried changinf Charset.Ansi to Charset.Auto and Charset.Unicode, with same result.

I've also tried changing the Marshalling of the string argument of funtion Bar to all available unmanaged string types, but no success. Some types marsharas types output load of gibberish, some resulted in memory exception.

Can anyone help in figuring out why the library is getting an empty string?

Comment: Can you try the changing the the type of the c++ parameter to char*?

Comment: @TYY Tried just now. Same Result. strlen(msg) = 0.

Comment: You can't expose an std::string to .NET client. You must expose char*, wchar_t* (or BSTR) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/type-marshalling

Comment: @SimonMourier: Thanks, improvement from previous builds. Only changing to char* didn't have any effect. But after changing the ```[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]``` to ```[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bstr)]``` the unmanaged dll can read 1 char of the string. No matter how long the original string, dll gets only first character of the argument string i.e strlin(msg):1.
Looks like I've been able to make progress thanks to you all.
Any further ideas how to effectively pass the whole string?

Comment: BSTR is probably a side effect, not good as I guess you're not working with BSTR. Add your changes as an update to the question, and/or post a reproducing project somewhere.

Comment: @SimonMourier: you are right, BSTR was a side effect, i'm not using BSTR in c++ code. False proggress reported.

Made the suggested edits, working on reproducing project.

Comment: `extern "C" int Bar(char* msg) { return strlen(msg); }` with `[DllImport("my.dll")] private static extern int Bar(string msg);` should work fine. Add the calling convention if you're running x86

Comment: I'm exporting the whole class foo of which bar() is a member of. I have the reproducing project ready, will share it.

Comment: get reproducible project from here https://github.com/JKaal/CSharp-Marshalling.git

Comment: You cannot obviously use an instance method for a dll export and use it as a static method (it misses the `this` pointer). Change it to this and it will work `static int bar(const char *msg);` (decorated name `?bar@foo@@SAHPEBD@Z`)

Comment: @SimonMourier: You make perfect sense. I had this hunch that how is it able to call a class member function without class instance. I tried marking the method 'static' and it worked. Thanks for that. If you could post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: With a dllexport on the class you don't even have to declare methods one by one like in the question, but non static ones will always require the `this` pointer as 1st arg.

Comment: I finally used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315051/using-a-class-defined-in-a-c-dll-in-c-sharp-code#answer-36574077) method to use instance of classes to call the exported member functions.